# Why is this graph turned?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I don't know why the graph is turned.

[image]

Here is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

img = plt.imread('tree.png')
img = img[:,:,0]
img = -img + 1

points_in = [[],[]]
points_out = [[],[]]

n = 100000
x = np.random.randint(img.shape[0],size = n)
y = np.random.randint(img.shape[1], size = n)

hit = 0
for i in range(n):
    if img[x[i],y[i]] != 0:
        points_in[0].append(x[i])
        points_in[1].append(y[i])
        hit += 1
    else:
        points_out[0].append(x[i])
        points_out[1].append(y[i])


square = img.shape[0] * img.shape[1] 
hit_rate = hit / n
result = square*hit/n
print(square, hit,hit_rate, result)

img = -img + 1
plt.imshow(img,cmap='gray')
plt.scatter(points_in[0],points_in[1],c='b',s=0.1)
plt.scatter(points_out[0],points_out[1],c='r',s=0.1)

plt.show()
```

I think a index of the list doesn't look like a problem.
I want to know why the graph is turned.

Comment: The array has row-major indexing, and you swapped rows with columns. It's not turned, it's mirrored along the diagonal (but since it seems the image is symmetrical, it looks similar).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you mixed up x and y coordinates:

1st index of img should be y, 2nd coordinate is x.

But you are using `img[x[i],y[i]]`.